# Failed to start the Kernel : Supporting extra quotes around strings is deprecated in traitlets 5.0

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

This is the error message displayed when I run the code in vs code:
C:\Anaconda3\envs\paul\lib\site-packages\traitlets\traitlets.py:2202: FutureWarning: Supporting extra quotes around strings is deprecated in traitlets 5.0. You can use 'hmac-sha256' instead of '"hmac-sha256"' if you require traitlets >=5.

I have tried the following and failed:

```
pip install pywin32==228

python -m pip install traitlets==4.3.3 --force-reinstall

python -m pip install pyzmq==19.0.2 --force-reinstall
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. This is how i fixed it.

1. first open a terminal in your project dir and open jupyter-notebook using a browser.
   try running the code there and check if kernel still crashes. For my case it was crashing becasue CUDnn was missing zlibwapi.dll file. This error didn't show up in jupyter log when i was running in vscode. So I downloaded it from:  http://www.winimage.com/zLibDll/zlib123dllx64.zip
2. After downloading, I put the dll file into {cudnn_root}/bin/ folder

This fixed my problem. Alternatively u can try to install my exact environment. Here is the link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1V2bash_j1tQNFfJtwOqXw-DmWGCe4Ive/view?usp=sharing. U can install it via pip install -r "filename.txt" command.